# NextAuth v4 Beta - DB Session - Storing extra fields from OAuth Login Response

Tags: mongodb, authentication, next.js, onelogin, next-auth

I was trying to implement the OneLogin authentication using the NextAuth for my NextJS app. I was able to get everything done and is connected to MongoDB. But trying to figure out how to store extra data received from OneLogin

Since I enabled the `debug` option in the NextAuth, I was able to see the following in logs in the `OAUTH_CALLBACK_RESPONSE` from OneLogin, and would like to include these three fields to the database's `users` collection against the user:

```
OAuthProfile: {
  given_name: "",
  family_name: "",
  preferred_username: "",
  ......
}
```

Because I want to set the `name` field of the User (that will be stored in database), with the value from `given_name` from the OAuthProfile (example above).

And also I would like to add an extra field like `auth_level` with a default value of "user", to denote that this User is by default a normal User. No elevated privileges' or anything.